# Is it possible to solve such a system?

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, recursion

I have the following two equations:

$$P_t = \frac{t-1}{t}P_{t-1} + \frac{1}{t}Q_{t-1}$$

$$Q_t = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{t-1}{t}Q_{t-1} - \frac{1}{t}P_{t-1}$$

with $P_0 = 0$ and $Q_0 = 0$. As time goes to infinity I know that both $P$ and $Q$ will equal 0.5. Notice that $t$ is time, so the system is not autonomous since time enters explicitly.

I have tried to solve it first by hand, exploiting the recursive structure, and even though there is a pattern at each step I cannot get an analytical expression for any $t$. I tried solving it on Matlab but have not succeeded: since the coefficients are time dependent, it seems I can only do this as a differential equation system and not as a difference equation system. Any suggestions? Is there a pen and paper method to solve this, or is there a way to do it Matlab or Python? Or can I cast this as a differential system?

Comment: Note that $(P^*,Q^*)=(.5,.5)$ does not solve the limit recursion $P^*=P^*+Q^*$, $Q^*=Q^*$.

Comment: Did, I missed 1/t in the last term on the first equation. I fixed this and it should now be so that P and Q equal 0.5 in the limit.

Comment: Now it settles to $(0.5,0.5)$ very nicely, but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: Sophie: How do you know beforehand that the convergence holds?

Comment: I drop the subscripts of variables and solve for P and Q, this gives the answer 0.5.

Comment: I know it is possible to solve this as a differential equation system, but I do not know how to correctly re-cast the quationse as a differenTIAL system. I have been looking on how to solve non-autonomous system of differENCE equations with time dependent coefficients but I always end up with differenTIAL systems. If you have any suggestions on how to recast the equations as differential ones then I might be able to solve it with a PC, numerically, maybe even analytically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a beautiful problem, as you are going to see in what follows.

First, you have correctly obtained the limit of the system, assuming that it exists. Now that we know it, let us rigorously show that it exists. Consider the change of unknowns $A_n = P_n - \frac 1 2, \ B_n = Q_n - \frac 1 2$ (motivated by the fact that $(\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$ is the limit of the system). We shall show that $A_n, B_n \to 0$.

Check that your system gets rewritten as

$$A_n = \left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right) A_{n-1} + \frac 1 n B_{n-1} \\ B_n = - \frac 1 n A_{n-1} + \left( 1 - \frac 1 n\right) B_{n-1} $$

with $A_0 = B_0 = - \frac 1 2$.

Rewrite this in matrix form as

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \frac 1 n & \frac 1 n \\ - \frac 1 n & 1 - \frac 1 n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A_{n-1} \\ B_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$$

and use recursion to expand this as

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \frac 1 n & \frac 1 n \\ - \frac 1 n & 1 - \frac 1 n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \frac 1 {n-1} & \frac 1 {n-1} \\ - \frac 1 {n-1} & 1 - \frac 1 {n-1} \end{pmatrix} \dots \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \frac 1 1 & \frac 1 1 \\ - \frac 1 1 & 1 - \frac 1 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} - \frac 1 2 \\ - \frac 1 2 \end{pmatrix} .$$

Note that we have been able to do this because the change of unknowns to $A_n$ and $B_n$ has annihilated the free term $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac 1 n \end{pmatrix}$ that was present when working in matrix form with $P_n$ and $Q_n$.

Dont't even think to explicitly compute that product of matrices: first, because it is probably impossible; second, because you are going to see that it is not necessary, anyway.

Let $M_n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \frac 1 n & \frac 1 n \\ - \frac 1 n & 1 - \frac 1 n \end{pmatrix}$. Note that $M_n$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ - b & a \end{pmatrix}$ and that any two matrices of this form commute (check it!). Since all the matrices $(M_n)_{n \ge 1}$ commute, they may be [*simultaneously* diagonalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization) over $\Bbb C$. This means that there exist an invertible matrix $X$ such that $M_n = X N_n X^{-1}$, where $N_n = \begin{pmatrix} x_n & 0 \\ 0 & \bar x_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $x_n, \bar x_n$ are the eigenvalues of $M_n$ (they are conjugate to each other because the characteristc equation of $M_n$ is of degree $2$ with real coefficients, therefore it has two complex-conjugated roots).

It is not difficult to compute the eigenvalues in the usual way and discover that $x_n = 1 - \frac 1 n + \frac {\rm i} n$. Why is this convenient? Because that ugly product of matrices becomes now a product of diagonal matrices, and this is easy to compute:

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = X \begin{pmatrix} x_n & 0 \\ 0 & \bar x_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_{n-1} & 0 \\ 0 & \bar x_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} \dots \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \bar x_1 \end{pmatrix} X^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} - \frac 1 2 \\ - \frac 1 2 \end{pmatrix} = \\ X \begin{pmatrix} x_n x_{n-1} \dots x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \overline {x_n x_{n-1} \dots x_1} \end{pmatrix} X^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} - \frac 1 2 \\ - \frac 1 2 \end{pmatrix} .$$

Note that if we manage to show that $\prod \limits _{n=1} ^\infty x_n = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} x_1 x_2 \dots x_n \to 0$ we are done. This is equivalent to showing that $\prod \limits _{n=1} ^\infty |x_n| = 0$. In order to study this, we shall take the logarithm of this product and show that $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \log |x_n| = - \infty$.

Using the value of $x_n$, the above series becomes $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \log \sqrt{\left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right)^2 + \frac 1 {n^2}}$; even simpler, since the square root gets out of the logarithm and of the series, let us study $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \log \left( 1 - \frac 2 n + \frac 2 {n^2} \right)$.

Note that this series has all the terms negative (because the arguments of $\log$ are numbers from $(0,1)$), so multiplying it by a minus sign turns it into a series with positive terms: $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty - \log \left( 1 - \frac 2 n + \frac 2 {n^2} \right)$. The nice thing about this is that for series with positive terms we have [the limit comparison convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_comparison_test): remembering that $\lim \limits _{x \to 0, x>0} \frac {- \log (1 - x)} x = 1$ and taking $x = \frac 2 n - \frac 2 {n^2}$, the limit comparison convergence test tells us that $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty - \log \left( 1 - \frac 2 n + \frac 2 {n^2} \right)$ has the same behaviour as $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \left( \frac 2 n - \frac 2 {n^2} \right) = \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \frac 2 n - \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \frac 2 {n^2}$; the first term is clearly divergent summing up to $+ \infty$, and the second is convergent. This shows that $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \log \left( 1 - \frac 2 n + \frac 2 {n^2} \right) = - \infty$ (note the sign change, since we have reverted to our series with negative terms). Exponentiating it gives ${\rm e} ^{- \infty} = 0$, so $\prod \limits _{n=1} ^\infty x_n = 0$, which is what we were after.

---

To obtain explicit formulae for $A_n$ and $B_n$, let us go back to the diagonalization formula

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = X \begin{pmatrix} x_n x_{n-1} \dots x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \overline {x_n x_{n-1} \dots x_1} \end{pmatrix} X^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} - \frac 1 2 \\ - \frac 1 2 \end{pmatrix} .$$

Since $X$ and $X^{-1}$ diagonalize every matrix $M_n$, they diagonalize $M_1$, for which the computations are easy: the eigenvalues are ${\rm i}$ and $-{\rm i}$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ {\rm i} \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -{\rm i} \end{pmatrix}$, therefore $M_n = X \begin{pmatrix} x_n & 0 \\ 0 & \bar x_n \end{pmatrix} X^{-1}$, where $X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ {\rm i} & -{\rm i} \end{pmatrix}$ and $X^{-1} = \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -{\rm i} \\ 1 & {\rm i} \end{pmatrix}$. Plugging these ingredients into the above expression, we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ {\rm i} & -{\rm i} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_n x_{n-1} \dots x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \overline {x_n x_{n-1} \dots x_1} \end{pmatrix} \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -{\rm i} \\ 1 & {\rm i} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} - \frac 1 2 \\ - \frac 1 2 \end{pmatrix} = - \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} \text{Re } x_1 x_2 \dots x_n + \text{Im } x_1 x_2 \dots x_n \\ \text{Re } x_1 x_2 \dots x_n - \text{Im } x_1 x_2 \dots x_n \end{pmatrix} ,$$

whence it finally follows that

$$P_n = \frac {1 - \text{Re } \prod \limits _{k=1} ^n \left( 1 - \frac 1 k + \frac {\rm i} k \right) - \text{Im } \prod \limits _{k=1} ^n \left( 1 - \frac 1 k + \frac {\rm i} k \right)} 2, \quad Q_n = \frac {1 - \text{Re } \prod \limits _{k=1} ^n \left( 1 - \frac 1 k + \frac {\rm i} k \right) + \text{Im } \prod \limits _{k=1} ^n \left( 1 - \frac 1 k + \frac {\rm i} k \right)} 2 .$$

I strongly doubt that one can find a closed formula for these.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your answer, it is very enlightening and it ties up to my little knowledge of dynamical systems. I have solved small 2x2 linear systems in the past by matrix diagonalization (only constant coefficient and autonomous problems), so this helps. I am curious though how could I get a function that would give me any $(P_n,Q_n)$ values by inputting $t$ and an initial condition. I suspect this involves a small change of variable from $A_n$ back to $P_n$ and using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, besides my question above, how did you get the term inside the summation with square root $(1-\frac{1}{n})^2+\frac{1}{n}$? If I remember correctly, with complex eigenvalues $a-bi,a+bi$ we only work with $a^2+b^2$, right?

Comment: @Sophie: I have expanded my answer. Concerning the modulus: if $x_n = 1 - \frac 1 n + \frac {\rm i} n$ then $|x_n| = |1 - \frac 1 n + \frac {\rm i} n| = \sqrt {\left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right)^2 + \left( \frac 1 n \right)^2}$.

Comment: By moving around the signs of $i$ inside the real/imaginary part of your expression properly, your expression can be combined to the closed form

$$P_t + i Q_t = \frac{1+i}{2}\left[1 - \frac{\Gamma(t-i)}{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(-i)}\right]$$

Comment: For $P_t - iQ_t$, just take the complex conjugate, i.e. $$P_t - i Q_t = \frac{1-i}{2}\left[1 - \frac{\Gamma(t+i)}{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(i)}\right]$$
To compute actual numbers, this might not that useful. However, this form allow us to derive the higher order asymptotic behavior of $P_t, Q_t$ from those of gamma functions.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you for your explanations. I understand how to derive the result now. However, one last question, how is it that you have $\text{Re}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{i}{n})$  and $\text{Im}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{i}{n})$ at the last stage? The reason I ask this is that in differential equation systems the imaginary terms somehow drop out at the end and we can get a real solution. I do not know how this happens hear, in a difference equation setting. I also notice that the eigenvalues only have the positive one in the products. What about the conjugate?

Comment: @achillehui Thank you for your input, I will look into this.

Comment: @Sophie: Don't forget that $\operatorname{Re} (a + b {\rm i}) = a$ and $\operatorname{Im} (a + b {\rm i}) = b$, so both *are real*. Therefore, everything you see there is real. Also, remember that $\operatorname{Re} \bar z = \operatorname{Re} z$ and $\operatorname{Im} \bar z = - \operatorname{Im} z$, so the conjugate is "absorbed" into a change of sign in front of $\operatorname{Im}$ that I have already taken care of in my answer.

Comment: @AlexM. I understand the significance of $\text{Re}(z)$ and $\text{Im}(z)$. What I am a bit confused on is how the product of the eigenvalues gives $\text{Re}(z)+\text{Im}(z)$. I did the multiplications by hand and some $i$'s did not vanish. I noticed, however, that I made mistakes, the imaginary numbers do cancel out. Thanks again!

Comment: No, no, no, the product of the eigenvalues indeed does *not* give that sum of $\operatorname{Re} z + \operatorname{Im} z$. Note that you also multiply the matrix with the products of eigenvalues both on the left and on the right by two square matrices, then again on the right by a vector. Finally you will obtain a vector with entries like $z + \bar z$ (this one evaluates to $2 \operatorname{Re} z$).

Comment: Yes, the eigenvectors come in as well. Thanks again AlexM.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too big for a comment.  A plot shows the two converge nicely to $(0.5,0.5)$.  The blue is $P_t$ and the purple is $Q_t$.  I tried rewriting the equations in variables $tP_t$ and $tQ_t$ and also $P+Q, P-Q$  but did not get anywhere

[image]

Comment: Ross, I missed a $1/t$ multiplying the last term of the first equation. How could I solve for such a system: non-autonomous system of difference equations? I know how to solve them when the coefficients are constant, by diagonalizing the coefficient matrix, but I suspect this will not work for a system that has coefficients that change through time, because $t$ enters explicitly.

Comment: While relevant before the OP's edit of the original question, I doubt that this answer has any usefulness now.

Comment: @AlexM.:  I have updated the plot

Comment: I know, and what I was saying is that now it doesn't help anybody in any way, it has made its point but it's no longer useful.